# Convert URLs in text file to browser bookmark file

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, bookmarks

#### Background

I have a text file with quite a lot of URLs in plain text on each row. I want to import these to [Pocket](http://www.getpocket.com).

I found that Pocket provides the ability to [import browser bookmark files](https://getpocket.com/import/browser) from Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari and make them into Pocket items.

#### Problem

How can a .txt file with URLs on each row, be made into a bookmark file?

For reference, when generating a bookmark file of my actual bookmarks from Chrome, a html file is generated with a certain code structure. At the top of the file code is: `<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>`.

#### Solutions

Unless there is some clever programmatic solution to directly convert .txt to bookmark html, I guess one way could be to create a temporary Chrome user and find some utility that imports text files as bookmarks, and then export the bookmarks as a bookmark file in html.

Any ideas?

*NB: I'm a Mac user.*

Comment: Well, what do you know! Just after posting this question, I found this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/batch-save-pocket/ihhiomekhplpdojbcaniaglcfopckaef?hl=en) which can batch-import URLs to Pocket. The immediate problem is solved for me, but I'm leaving this question open because it may interest people with other use-cases.

Comment: You can answer your own question in any case!

Comment: @Winterflags you can post an answer to your question

Comment: The Chrome extension linked isn't really a solution to the actual question, it was however a solution to my particular problem.